# Seconds to byte position in audio file

Tags: math, audio, vb6

I have a wave file (PCM). 
I have removed the header and read the audio data into a byte array.

I would like to find out the byte position of a given time value (for example  6,72911493013085E-02 seconds).

I have written a converter function:

```
Public Function SecondsToBytePos(ByVal uSeconds As Double, ByVal uSamplesPerSecond As Long, ByVal uChannels As Long, ByVal uBitsPerSample) As Long

    Dim lRet&
    lRet = (uSeconds * ((uSamplesPerSecond * uChannels * uBitsPerSample) / 8))

    SecondsToBytePos = lRet

End Function
```

However when I use

SecondsToBytePos(6,72911493013085E-02, 48000, 1, 16)

I get the even value 6460.

This can not be correct because the byte array is zero-based, so the value needs to be odd.

2 bytes make up 1 double / float value, so even values may never occur.

Does anybody see any flaw in my converter function?

Thank you for the help.

Edit: Here is a different approach:

```
Public Function SecondsToBytePos(ByVal uSeconds As Double, ByVal uSamplesPerSecond As Long, ByVal uChannels As Long, ByVal uBitsPerSample) As Long

    Dim g_lBlockAlign As Long=2

    Dim lret&
    lret = (uSeconds * ((uSamplesPerSecond * uChannels * uBitsPerSample) / 8))

    If (lret Mod g_lBlockAlign) > 0 Then
        Dim lRem&
        lRem = (lret \ g_lBlockAlign) + 1
        lret = lRem * g_lBlockAlign 
    End If

    SecondsToBytePos = lret

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption that the return value needs to be odd is wrong - since you're converting to bytes and not samples or frames.

If you want the byte position of the 1st sample of the 1st channel starting at time uSeconds:

```
frameNumber = Floor(uSeconds * uSamplesPerSecond)
bytePos = frameNumber * numChannels * bitsPerSample/8
```

bytePos will be a multiple of numChannels*bitsPerSample/8

If you want the byte position of the 1st sample of *ANY* channel starting at time uSeconds:

```
sampleNumber = Floor(uSeconds * uSamplesPerSecond * numChannels)
bytePos = sampleNumber * bitsPerSample/8
```

Here bytePos will be a multiple of bitsPerSample/8

I would suspect you want the frameNumber as it your data aligned - if you were wanting to play back from that position for example your left and right would stay left and right.

Comment: The file is mono. A sample is 1 double / flat value, meaning 2 bytes. Do you still that my assumption is wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is for every condition. Consider a simple example. 1 second of 48kHz audio, mono, 16-bit. You are first converting to number of bytes, which is 96000. Then you are using seconds to index into that number. If you asked for the byte at 0.5 seconds then you would get 48000. If you ask for the byte at (0.5 + (1/48000.0)) you are going to get 48001. The point of my answer is that you need to retain the framing you desire before the indexing and *then* convert that answer to bytes.

Comment: I don't trust "Floor". I have added another approach to my posting. Can I also use this BlockAlign approach?

Comment: Your added code will work only for 16-bit samples and is a bit convoluted. I don't know why you don't trust floor. Since seconds are floating point then you'll get answers like the 8.952th sample. If your requirements are that it return the 8th sample then use floor. Otherwise use midpoint rounding.